# Connect to multiple Magento websites

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I need to create a php batch script, that connects to multiple Magento websites, and perform some database updates. They are all running on the same webserver.

I am hoping to be able to create one single looping script, instead of multiple scripts (one for each website). But I am also hoping to use the Magento Model in the php code (app/Mage.php etc).

How to I control which website/database the Magento model uses?

Comment: Are these websites using a single Magento install with a single database?

Comment: No, there are separate Magento installations and databases for each website.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script which cycles through all your magento installations include their Mage.php and get the database handler to run your query.
Something like this:

```
<?php
$mySql = 'UPDATE ... WHERE ...;';
$magentos = array('/web/magento1/', '/web/magento2/');
foreach ($magentos as $m) {
    require_once($m.'app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->query($mySql);
}
```

Maybe you also add a transaction around your sql and output the results of your queries to be sure that everything worked as expected.
To control which website to use add the website to your array and change Mage::app('default');

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about something like what you are suggesting. But I do not think it is working. I guess I also need to change some SERVER-variables to switch between websites...